# CSS Isolation issue with blazor

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core-5.0

My page has this filename

**Page.razor.css**

and I defined these css properties for my table

```
.table .table-head,
.table .table-body {
    -ms-grid-columns: 4% 10% auto 8% 15% 9% 8% 12% 12% !important;
    grid-template-columns: 4% 10% 22% 8% 15% 9% 8% 12% auto !important;
}

.table .table-body .more-details {
    -ms-grid-column: 1 !important;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 9 !important;
    grid-column: 1/10 !important;
}
```

at runtime, I inspected my table and I see that I am getting my CSS from app.css

My project used to be a .NET 3.1 app but I upgraded to .NET 5 for the CSS Isolation features.

In my _Hosts.cshtml

```
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="AppName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I haven't converted all my pages to use CSS Isolation yet but am in the process. So I can't completely delete app.css from the project.

Some of my other pages work great with css isolation. This one isn't and I don't understand why

Comment: How about upgrading to .NET 6 (released yesterday)? Maybe they fixed this behavior?

Comment: One `<link>` in your _Hosts.cshtml is self-terminated, the other isn't. Maybe this could be an issue, too?